# Can't change Metadata after Validation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, .net-4.8, propertydescriptor

I'm trying to implement a validation with attributes that I can change on runtime using `AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider` and `TypeDescriptor.AddProvider`.
It works fine if it is set only once, but if you want to change provider **after** validation using `Validator.ValidateObject` or `Entity Framework` *(it has automatic entity validation on `SaveChanges`)* it will suddenly stuck on the provider you have set and there is no way to change it.

Lets assume that we have this class with two metadata's:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public class CreateMetadata
    {   
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
        
    public class UpdateMetadata : CreateMetadata
    {
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Create person and metadata instances:

```cs
Person person = new Person();

TypeDescriptionProvider createMetaProvider;
TypeDescriptionProvider updateMetaProvider;
            
createMetaProvider = new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(
    type: typeof(Person), 
    associatedMetadataType: typeof(Person.CreateMetadata));

updateMetaProvider = new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(
    type: typeof(Person),
    associatedMetadataType: typeof(Person.UpdateMetadata));
```

Lets validate person first using **Create** metadata, then **Update**:

```cs
Validate(person, createMetaProvider);
Validate(person, updateMetaProvider);
```

```cs
static void Validate(object obj, TypeDescriptionProvider metadataProvider)
{
    TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(metadataProvider, typeof(Person));

    var context = new ValidationContext(obj);
    var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

    Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, context, validationResults);

    string errors = string
        .Join("\n", validationResults
        .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));

    Console.WriteLine($"{errors}\n");

    TypeDescriptor.RemoveProvider(metadataProvider, typeof(Person));
}
```

Output:

```
The Name field is required.

The Name field is required.
```

As you may notice, it uses **Create** metadata in **both** cases.
Lets swap them:

```cs
Validate(person, updateMetaProvider);
Validate(person, createMetaProvider);
```

Output:

```
The Name field is required.
The Password field is required.

The Name field is required.
The Password field is required.
```

The same result. First provider is used in both cases.

As I mentioned before, this also happens with **Entity Framework** after saving changes.

The only solution I found is using custom validation, but that can't be used with EF.

Though it is possible to disable automatic validation in EF, I consider this more  as hack than a solution.

Here's my validation implementation:

```cs
static void Validate(object obj, TypeDescriptionProvider metadataProvider)
{
    TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(metadataProvider, typeof(Person));

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj))
    {
        foreach(ValidationAttribute attribute in property.Attributes.OfType<ValidationAttribute>())
        {
            if (attribute.IsValid(property.GetValue(obj)))
                continue;

            sb.AppendLine(attribute.FormatErrorMessage(property.Name));
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{sb}");

    TypeDescriptor.RemoveProvider(metadataProvider, typeof(Person));
}
```

Usage:

```cs
Validate(person, updateMetaProvider);
Validate(person, createMetaProvider);
```

Output:

```
The Name field is required.

The Name field is required.
The Password field is required.
```

[Full Source Code](https://gist.github.com/ranstar74/b821382cf131410017dd2a2fa99471e2)

> **UPDATE 1**: Richard Deeming found that validator caches attributes internally, which explains described behaviour.
> [ValidationAttributeStore](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/ValidationAttributeStore.cs)

Comment: [TypeDescriptor.AddProvider Method (System.ComponentModel) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.addprovider?view=net-6.0#System_ComponentModel_TypeDescriptor_AddProvider_System_ComponentModel_TypeDescriptionProvider_System_Type_): It is possible to add multiple type description providers for the same type or object. If this occurs, **the first type description provider encountered that provides type information will be used exclusively**.

Comment: But it also says that I can use RemoveProvider, and its actually works until I validate object

Comment: Have you tried passing in the instance, rather than the type? *"The `AddProvider` method that takes an `Object` parameter affects only that single instance of the component specified. In contrast, the other overload, which takes a `Type` parameter, affects all instances of the component described by that type."*

Comment: Yep, it gives the same result. Plus it works fine with my validation, so there's definitely some issue in Validator class.

Comment: Looks like [the internal `ValidationAttributeStore` class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/ValidationAttributeStore.cs) caches the validation attributes in a dictionary, and [the `Validator` class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/Validator.cs,14) uses a single static instance of that store.

Comment: Damn, they didn't even added a way to clear it... It totally ruins whole reflection concept

Comment: IIRC, the metadata providers were introduced as a way to add metadata to compiler-generated classes - specifically for Entity Framework models reverse-engineered from an existing database. I don't think they were ever intended to be used in this way. I'd be inclined to use separate view-models with the relevant validation on them instead.

Comment: Well I do use it for EF generated classes, I just have two forms with different fields for the same model. Thanks for your help and time anyway.